# Mongoose adds _id to all nested objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When creating a document with nested objects (e.g. an array of objects), each object is given its own _id. For example, my schema looks like this:

```
mongoose = require "mongoose"

Schema = mongoose.Schema

schema = new Schema
  name:
    type: String
    required: true
    unique: true
    trim: true

  lists: [
    list:
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
      required: true
      ref: "List"
    allocations: [
      allocation:
        type: Number
        required: true
    ]
  ]

  createdAt:
    type: Date
    default: Date.now

  updatedAt:
    type: Date

# Ensure virtual fields are serialised.
schema.set "toJSON",
  virtuals: true

exports = module.exports = mongoose.model "Portfolio", schema
```

Every object in the `lists` array is given an _id, as is every `allocation` object in the `lists.allocations` array, when documents are eventually created. This seems like overkill and bloats the document, but is there a reason MongoDB (or Mongoose) needs the document to contain this additional information? If not, I'd like to prevent it from happening so that the only _id is on the root document.

Furthermore, Mongoose automatically creates a virtual `id` for `_id`, which I need because my client code expects a field `id`. This is why I'm having virtuals returned with JSON. However, because there are `_id` fields all throughout the document, not just at the root, this virtual duplicates *all* of them. If there is no way to prevent the additional _id fields, how can I get a virtual to only apply only to the root document _id? Or if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do with it, what would it be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve both issues with the same technique: by using explicit schemas for each nested object type and setting their `_id` and `id` options to `false`. It seems that when nesting objects that you define "inline", Mongoose creates schemas for each of those objects behind the scenes. Since the default for a schema is `_id: true` and `id: true`, they will get an `_id` as well as have a virtual `id`. But by overriding this with an explicit schema, I can control the `_id` creation. More code, but I get what I want:

```
mongoose = require "mongoose"

Schema = mongoose.Schema

AllocationSchema = new Schema
  allocation:
    type: Number
    required: true
,
  _id: false
   id: false

mongoose.model "Allocation", AllocationSchema

ListsSchema = new Schema
  list:
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    required: true
    ref: "List"
  allocations: [AllocationSchema]
,
  _id: false
   id: false

mongoose.model "Lists", ListsSchema

PortfolioSchema = new Schema
  name:
    type: String
    required: true
    unique: true
    trim: true

  lists: [ListsSchema]

  createdAt:
    type: Date
    default: Date.now

  updatedAt:
    type: Date
```

Comment: In version (3.6) I am able to simply add _id: false to the subdocs right in the main schema without a need to make separate sub schemas

Comment: If you are looking for a JavaScript solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254008/stop-mongoose-from-created-ids-for-subdocument-arrays

Answer (score 11):

@neverfox thanks for info, I just adding the code for Nodejs

```
var _incidents = mongoose.Schema({
  name : {type : String},
  timestamp: {type : Number},
  _id : {id:false}
});


_schema = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: {type: String, required: true},
   user_id: {type: String, required: true}, 
   start_time: {type: Number, required: true},  
    incidents : [_incidents],
});
```

Comment: FYI I was able to use just false instead of {id:false} for the value of _id in subdocuments