# Stop Mongoose from creating _id property for sub-document array items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

If you have subdocument arrays, Mongoose automatically creates ids for each one. Example:

```
{
    _id: "mainId"
    subDocArray: [
      {
        _id: "unwantedId",
        field: "value"
      },
      {
        _id: "unwantedId",
        field: "value"
      }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to tell Mongoose to not create ids for objects within an array?

Answer (score 441, accepted):

It's simple, you can define this in the subschema :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // your subschema content
}, { _id : false });

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    // schema content
    subSchemaCollection : [subSchema]
});

var model = mongoose.model('tablename', schema);
```

Comment: will this skip `_id` fields even in the subSchema collection, or only in the case where the subSchema is being used to embed as array of sub-document items? I ask this particularly because of my own [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151433/mongoose-inserts-extra-id-in-array-of-objects-corresponding-to-related-entity) on SO today.

Comment: I use two levels of nested sub-schema collections. In other words, I have a subSchema collection similar to your example. Within that, I use another different sub-schema collection. I want only the first level sub-schema model instances to not use ids, but the second level (nested) sub-schema model instances need to have ids. When I use your solution, that is, specifying `{ _id: false }`, both levels of sub-schema are without ids. Any way to work around this behavior?

Comment: Have you try, for the third level to set `{ _id : true }` ?

Comment: what I tried yesterday was change this: `let studentSchema = new Schema({ studentId: { type: ObjectId, ref: Student.modelName }, performance: [performanceSchema] }, { _id: false });` to this: `let studentSchema = new Schema({ _id: false, id: false, studentId: { type: ObjectId, ref: Student.modelName }, performance: [performanceSchema] });` and that stopped `_id` creation on the `studentSchema` but retained `_id` creation on the objects in the `performance` array of sub-documents. Not sure if both `_id: false` and `id: false` are needed.

Answer (score 214):

You can create sub-documents without schema and avoid `_id`. Just add `_id: false` to your subdocument declaration.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   field1: {
      type: String
   },
   subdocArray: [{
      _id: false,
      field: { type: String }
   }]
});
```

This will prevent the creation of an `_id` field in your subdoc.

Tested in Mongoose `v5.9.10`

Answer (score 61):

Additionally, if you use an object literal syntax for specifying a sub-schema, you may also just add `_id: false` to supress it.

```
{
   sub: {
      property1: String,
      property2: String,
      _id: false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

I'm using mongoose 4.6.3 and all I had to do was add _id: false in the schema, no need to make a subschema.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId
    subDocArray: [
      {
        _id: false,
        field: "String"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make unique across entire collection?

Comment: Probably not with this method, but you could always try. `_id` is a field rather than a constraint.

Comment: if during the creation of that sub-document, i explicitly assign ```_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()```, would that _id be unique across collection then?

Comment: just open a new stack overflow, this way you can get many people to answer at once~

Answer (score 7):

You can use either of the one

```
var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
//subschema fields    

},{ _id : false });
```

or

```
var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
//subschema content
_id : false    

});
```

Check your mongoose version before using the second option

Answer (score 5):

NestJS example for anyone looking for a solution with decorators

```js
@Schema({_id: false})
export class MySubDocument {
    @Prop()
    id: string;
}
```

Below is some additional information from the Mongoose Schema Type definitions for `id` and `_id`:

```
/**
* Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the document's _id field
* cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString.
*/
id?: boolean;

/**
* Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema
* constructor. The type assigned is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDB's default behavior. If you
* don't want an _id added to your schema at all, you may disable it using this option.
*/
_id?: boolean;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a predefined schema (with _id) as subdocument (without _id), you can do as follow in theory :

```
const sourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    key : value
})
const subSourceSchema = sourceSchema.clone().set('_id',false);
```

But that didn't work for me. So I added that :

```
delete subSourceSchema.paths._id;
```

Now I can include subSourceSchema in my parent document without _id.
I'm not sure this is the clean way to do it, but it work.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `false` is not a valid type at path `id`.

```
_id: { id: false },
```

If adding this line makes your app show the error message mentioned above, you might be using the newest mongoose 7 module versions.

To solve it, modify the mentioned line by adding an underscore `_` before the `id` in the `{ _id: false }` syntax on that line. So, that line should now look like this:

```
_id: { _id: false },
```