# Mongodb internal ID with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

[image: Screenshot of result]

So I just recently begun playing with the MEAN stack and I noticed that mongo (with mongoose) was creating embedded _id props (the yellow highlight) for objects within arrays. Wanted to know if anyone knew if this was a normal occurrence and if its ok or if it signals an issue in my schema design (the schema pretty much looks like that). Pardon my horrible coloring. Thanks.

Comment: This is an expected behavior for sub-objects in your schema. If you don't want those ids check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254008/stop-mongoose-from-created-ids-for-subdocument-arrays

Comment: Use `{ "_id": false}` in your schema definition for the "sub-document". It's an option like `Schema({ //def here },{ "_id": false })` on the embedded schema definition to turn this off. If you want to turn it off that is. It's probably quite handy to have.