# MongooseJS - how to define a custom type

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using "mongoose": "4.9.8", I want to define a type for consistency and reuse.
I know the concept, but I'm a little stuck on the syntax, For instance, say my mongoose schema looks like this

```
const thingsSchema = new Schema({
    thing: {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }   
    ,location: {
        city: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
        ,state: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
        ,country: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
    }   
});
```

what I really want to do is use "Location" model/type
over again elsewhere, and have location not be required...like this:

```
const thingsSchema = new Schema({
    thing: {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }   
    ,location: {
        type: Location
        ,required: false
    }   
});
```

I think it's done something like this - but Im unsure.

```
const Location: {
        city: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
        ,state: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
        ,country: {
            type: String
            ,required: false
        }
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested objects in mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596625/nested-objects-in-mongoose-schemas)

Comment: Possible, yes, the second answer there makes a go at it - and it may be right, but it is poorly explained. Thx for the link.