# Add object to object array if an object property is not given yet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Use Case**

I've got a collection `band_profiles` and I've got a collection `band_profiles_history`. The history collection is supposed to store a band_profile snapshot every 24 hour and therefore I am using MongoDB's recommended format for historical tracking: Each month+year is it's own document and in an object array I will store the bandProfile snapshot along with the current day of the month.

**My models:**

A document in `band_profiles_history` looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc406955db4cbffe0a8"),
    "month" : 7,
    "tag_lowercased" : "9yq88gg",
    "year" : 2017,
    "values" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc41c073a7418fead91"),
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5989a65d0f39d9fd70cde1fe"),
                "tag" : "9YQ88GG",
                "name_normalized" : "example name1",
            },
            "day" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc41c073a7418fead91"),
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5989a65d0f39d9fd70cde1fe"),
                "tag" : "9YQ88GG",
                "name_normalized" : "new name",
            },
            "day" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And a document in `band_profiles`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5989a6190f39d9fd70cddeb1"),
    "tag" : "9V9LRGU",
    "name_normalized" : "example name",
    "tag_lowercased" : "9v9lrgu",
}
```

This is how I upsert my documents into band_profiles_history at the moment:

```
BandProfileHistory.update(
  { tag_lowercased: tag, year, month},
  { $push: {
        values: { day, profile }
    }
  }, 
  { upsert: true }
)
```

**My problem:**

I only want to insert ONE snapshot for every day. Right now it would always push a new object into the object array `values` no matter if I already have an object for that day or not. How can I achieve that it would only push that object if there is no object for the current day yet?

Answer (score 1):

Putting mongoose aside for a moment:

There is an operation [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) that will add an element to an array if it doesn't already exists.

#### Caveat:

> If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields and values and the fields are in the same order. As such, field order matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element.

Since you are trying to add an entire document you are subjected to this restriction.

So I see the following solutions for you:

### Solution 1:

Read in the array, see if it contains the element you want and if not push it to the `values` array with `push`.

This has the **disadvantage** of **NOT** being an atomic operation meaning that you could end up would duplicates anyways. This could be acceptable if you ran a periodical clean up job to remove duplicates from this field on each document.

It's up to you to decide if this is acceptable.

### Solution 2:

Assuming you are putting the field `_id` in the subdocuments of your `values` field, stop doing it. Assuming mongoose is doing this for you (because it does, from what I understand) stop it from doing it like it says here: [Stop mongoose from creating `_id` for subdocument in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254008/stop-mongoose-from-creating-id-property-for-sub-document-array-items).

Next you need to ensure that the fields in the document **always have the same order**, because order matters when comparing documents in the `addToSet` operation as stated in the citation above.

### Solution 3

Change the schema of your `band_profiles_history` to something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc406955db4cbffe0a8"),
    "month" : 7,
    "tag_lowercased" : "9yq88gg",
    "year" : 2017,
    "values" : {
       "1": { "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc41c073a7418fead91"),
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5989a65d0f39d9fd70cde1fe"),
                "tag" : "9YQ88GG",
                "name_normalized" : "example name1"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "_id" : ObjectId("599e3bc41c073a7418fead91"),
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5989a65d0f39d9fd70cde1fe"),
                "tag" : "9YQ88GG",
                "name_normalized" : "new name"
            }
        }

}
```

Notice that the day field became the key for the subdocuments on the `values`. Notice also that `values` is now an `Object` instead of an `Array`.

No you can run an update query that would update `values.<day>` only if `values.<day>` didn't exist.

Personally I don't like this as it is using the fact that JSON doesn't allow duplicate keys to support the schema.

Comment: After reading I'd favour solution 3 but I have no idea how a mongoose schema would look like to realize associative object arrays? I can't rely on addToSet as profiles will always changes (there are object properties which change very frequently on the same day).

Comment: What about a mix of solution 1 but with the `push` operator? Would that be acceptable for your requirements?

Comment: A mix of what solutions do you mean? I meant I can't rely on the addToSet because the profile I am inserting will be different. So that wouldn't prevent me from inserting multiple profiles for the same day unfortunately. Hence solution 3 is still my favourite unless I didn't understand you correctly

Comment: Forget the "mix" I misspoke. Solution one is what I meant. I dislike schemas like solution 3.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sadly mongodb does not support uniqueness of a field in an array of a collection. You can see there is [major bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068) opened for 7 years and not closed yet(that is a shame in my opinion).

What you can do from here is limited and all is on application level. I had same problem and solve it in application level. Do something like this:

1. First read your document with document `_id` and `values.day`.
2. If your reading in step 1 returns null, that means there is no record on values array for given day, so you can `push` the new value(I assume `band_profile_history` has record with `_id` value).
3. If your reading in step 1 returns a document, that means values array has a record for given day. In that case you can use `set`operation with `$`operator.

Like others said, they will be not atomic but while you are dealing with your problem in application level, you can make whole bunch of code **synchronized**. There will be 2 queries to run on mongodb among of 3 queries. Like below:

`db.getCollection('band_profiles_history').find({"_id": "1", "values.day": 3})`

if returns null:

`db.getCollection('band_profiles_history').update({"_id": "1"}, {$push: {"values": {<your new band profile history for given day>}}})`

if returns not null:

`db.getCollection('band_profiles_history').update({"_id": "1", "values.day": 3}, {$set: {"values.$": {<your new band profile history for given day>}}})`

Answer (score 0):

To check if object is empty

```
{ field: {$exists: false} }
```

or if it is an array

```
 { field: {$eq: []} }
```

Mongoose also supports `field: {type: Date}` so you can use it instead counting a days, and do updates only for current date.

Comment: I haven't even tried it but I wonder why I would be able to define a condition like $exists inside of the values object?

Comment: Maybe because you want to $push based on some conditon? You dont have to try it, you know, originlly if ask question you not trying the answer

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense in your answer I am not even passing the profileData I want to push into the values object anymore

Comment: Because I cant see the schema and I cant see how exactly  `band_profiles` beieng inserted and how are you setting your fields I have updated my answer.