# How to avoid generating object id while creating subobject in array in mongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, mongoose

In my document i have array of `images` in which each image has `url` and `public_id`.

I want only the `url` `public_id` but additional parameter of `_id` is also stored. Which i want to avoid.

Stored in the database as:

```
"images": [
      {
        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1665806337/vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b.png",
        "public_id": "vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b",
        "_id": "634a4db7177280021c56737c"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1665806337/vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b.png",
        "public_id": "vivans/po0zh7eots60azadasdb",
        "_id": "634a4db7177280021c56737d"
      }
    ],
```

Mongoose Schema

```
const imageArray = new mongoose.Schema({
url: { type: String },
public_id: { type: String },
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    images: [imageArray],
});
```

My Post request

```
{
"images": [
    {
      "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1665806337/vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b.png",
      "public_id": "vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpurb6xes/image/upload/v1665806337/vivans/po0zh7eots60azad3y5b.png",
      "public_id": "vivans/po0zh7eots60azadasdb"
    }
  ],
}
```

How to get rid of _id stored in the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254008/stop-mongoose-from-creating-id-property-for-sub-document-array-items
Your question has already a number of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schema class can receive a second parameter, which is used to pass some options, one of them is "_id", which is a boolean value, so you just have to provide this second parameter with the _id property as false in order to avoid create the _id property in your documents.

This way:

```
const imageArray = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: { type: String },
    public_id: { type: String },
}, { _id: false }
);
```

You can look the entire options list in the official docs: [Mongoose Schema - options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options)