# Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these mongoose schemas:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    "pieces": Number, 
    "item": { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }
});

var cartSchema= new Schema({
    "items": [ItemSchema]
});
```

but when I want to push a new item in items, mongoose add an _id field(on the new item) but I don't understand why.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881832/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add item without `_id` field then you should add `{ _id: false }` in `ItemSchema`.

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    "pieces": Number, 
    "item": { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }
}, { _id: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type assigned is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDB's default behavior. If you don't want an _id added to your schema at all, you may disable it using this option.

You can only use this option on sub-documents. Mongoose can't save a document without knowing its id, so you will get an error if you try to save a document without an _id.

Link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

Comment: No. I found that I can remove the _id field with `{ _id: false }`

Comment: You can only use this option on sub-documents. Mongoose can't save a document without knowing its id, so you will get an error if you try to save a document without an _id.

Comment: Infact I wanted to delete _id field on sub-document

Comment: you should've been more clear in the question. No worries... Can you accept this answer?