# is mongoose generated sub-document _id unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Using the following mongoose schema

```
mongoose.Schema({
    world: String,
    color: [{ name: String }]
});
```

Gives me document that have sub-documents containing `_id` fields.

```
{ _id: 'a9ec8475bf0d285e10ca8d42'
  world: 'matrix', 
  color: [
    { name: 'blue',  _id: '4a8c0e12135fa32e13db9ce9' },
    { name: 'red',   _id: '4a8c0a62254cd32e13db4ad8' },
    { name: 'white', _id: '4a8c04e2687ea32e13db1da7' }
]
```

I want to know if each of these sub-documents `_id` are unique across all documents, or only across the nested level it is in.

**Edit**: the sub-document doesn't refer to another collection, it's created with the plain mongoose schema above.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field

Comment: @SergeK. This doesn't mention _ids of sub-documents.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the sub-document references another collection.
If my assumption  is right then the nested documents you have are only unique only on the nested level.

Comment: It doesn't refer to another collection. It's created with simple mongoose schema in the question.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to insert into the collection?

Comment: It's a mongoose operation: ```new model({ world: 'matrix', color: [{name: 'red'}, {name: 'blue'}, {name: 'white'}] })```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Mongoose. Mongoose creates schemas for each of those nested objects behind the scenes. That means the _id is only unquie on the nested level.

[Look at this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881832/mongoose-adds-id-to-all-nested-objects) on how to prevent this from happening

Comment: is there a way to make this _id unique across entire collection?

Comment: You can assign the _id value by yourself. there are UUID packages on npm to achieve that.